# RealURL: Correct strategy for menus and link to front page?

Tags: typo3, typoscript, realurl

## The Scenario

I have a website with several autogenerated menus:

- Main menu ("root level" pages)
- Tree menu (full tree down to current page)
- Breadcrumb (only `.ACT`)

Now I see two possibilities regarding these menus and the **RealURL** extension.

## Strategy A: Root as Front Page

I will create the page tree like so:

```
⊛ www.site.tld 
 ↳ Page 1
 ↳ Page 2
 ↳ Page 3
```

### Pros & Cons

- Con: I will have to manually add a link to the "Front Page" (content from page "www.site.tld") to all permutations of the menus (as this is not on the same physical level as the other "root level" pages)
- Pro: RealURL will per default render all links to the front page (the root page) as `/`

## Strategy B: Front Page as Separate Page in Tree

I will create the page tree like so:

```
⊛ www.site.tld 
 ↳ Front page
 ↳ Page 1
 ↳ Page 2
 ↳ Page 3
```

### Pros & Cons

- Pro: A link to the "Front Page" is automatically added to all permutations of the menus (as this is an explicit page on the correct level)
- Con: RealURL will per default render all links to the front page as `/front-page/` while I want it to link as `/`

## Best Practice?

Is there a best practice in the **front-page-as-root vs. front-page-as-separate-page** question? I.e, should I go with A and manually extend the menus, or with B (if so, how to configure RealURL to render the correct links)?

## Edit: The Answer

[Phil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/754052/phil) provided me with a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6008679/realurl-correct-strategy-for-menus-and-link-to-front-page/6012223#6012223) to the specific problem. **Go with strategy B, but let the page "Front page" be a link (`dokType` = shortcut) to the root (the page "www.site.tld")**. This will fix the menus *and* the links. ("Front page" being a shortcut, contents will reside on "www.site.tld".)

If anyone knows of alternatives to this one, please let me know. I do believe, however, that this will satisfy my needs concerning this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see 2 solutions (if I really understand youre question).

1. Put the Front page type to link, and link it to /
2. If you have access to the .htaccess, redirect /front-page/ to /

The solution B is easier, and it can be done without a special RealURL config

Comment: **1) Yes! Of course.** How did I not think of that? Thank you very much. As for 2), yes, I can easily redirect `/front-page/` to `/` but that will not prevent RealURL from *generating* the `/front-page/` links where I want it to generate `/` instead.